# Parse iOS facebook login fails

Tags: facebook, authentication, parse-platform, ios8

I am using parse facebook login for new users of my app. Most users are able to use it without a problem and I have successfully tested all Facebook login scenarios. Some users, however, report that when they press the login button they see brief activity indicator and then nothing happens. In code, no error is registered but the user is not brought beyond the login page to the app's initial screen. The problem resolved if the user deletes the app from their Facebook app settings and then tries again.  Has anyone else experienced this and/or found a solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this ever got resolved for you.

There are multiple possible causes for this of course including your own code. However, we've seen a similar issue with 2 causes / solutions.

UX-wise we detect multiple failed logins (typically with no error code) and then pop a notification telling the user how to solve. Still digging for a code-level solution that'll solve either of these issues permanently (if you found one, please post!) but hope these help & let you know you're not crazy.

---

**Issue #1:** User is logged into multiple Facebook accounts from the same device (e.g. a primary account and an org or 2ndary account).

**Fix #1:** Have user log out of all Facebook instances (app, safari, iOS settings) and then log back in.

---

**Issue #2:** User has rejected Facebook permissions.

**Fix #2:** For iOS, make sure Your App is toggled on in Settings -> Facebook -> Your App